# How to generate pdf files _with_ utf-8 multibyte characters using Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf, unicode

I've got a "little" problem with Zend Framework Zend_Pdf class. Multibyte characters are stripped from generated pdf files. E.g. when I write aąbcčdeę it becomes abcd with lithuanian letters stripped.

I'm not sure if it's particularly Zend_Pdf problem or php in general.

Source text is encoded in utf-8, as well as the php source file which does the job.

Thank you in advance for your help ;)

P.S. I run Zend Framework v. 1.6 and I use FONT_TIMES_BOLD font. FONT_TIMES_ROMAN does work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Zend_Pdf` supports UTF-8 in version 1.5 of Zend Framework.  However, the standard PDF fonts support only the Latin1 character set.  This means you can't use `Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_TIMES_BOLD` or any other "built-in" font.  To use special characters you must load another TTF font that includes characters from other character sets.

I use Mac OS X, so I tried the following code and it produces a PDF document with the correct characters.

```
$pdfDoc = new Zend_Pdf();
$pdfPage = $pdfDoc->newPage(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_LETTER);

// load TTF font from Mac system library
$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath('/Library/Fonts/Times New Roman Bold.ttf');
$pdfPage->setFont($font, 36);

$unicodeString = 'aąbcčdeę';
$pdfPage->drawText($unicodeString, 72, 720, 'UTF-8');

$pdfDoc->pages[] = $pdfPage;
$pdfDoc->save('utf8.pdf');
```

See also this bug log:  http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-3649

Answer (score 1):

I believe Zend_Pdf got UTF-8 support in 1.5 - What version of Zend Framework are you running?

Also - what font are you trying to render with? Have you tried alternate fonts?

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure that you are setting the character encoding as this example from the manual?

```
// Draw the string on the page
$pdfPage->drawText($unicodeString, 72, 720, 'UTF-8');
```

If you're stuck into having to use a **bold** font, maybe try one of the other bold fonts?

```
Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_COURIER_BOLD
Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_TIMES_BOLD
Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA_BOLD
```

Answer (score 0):

ZF v. 1.6, TIMES_BOLD (as I understand thats the only way to make text bold?)