# Unicode characters not showing in Zend_Pdf?

Tags: pdf, unicode, utf-8

```
require_once 'Zend/Pdf.php';
$pdf = new Zend_Pdf();
$page = $pdf->newPage(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
$pdf->pages[] = $page;
$page->setFont(Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA), 10);
$page->drawText("Bogus Russian: это фигня", 100, 400, "UTF-8");
$pdfData = $pdf->render();
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=output.pdf"); 
header("Content-type: application/x-pdf"); 
echo $pdfData;
```

I can't get the Russian characters to show up! I've managed to get them to show up as:

```
Russian: ???????????
Russian: ÐÐ¾Ð¼Ð¼ÑÐ½Ð
Russian: 
and
Russian: ><
```

Answer (score 1):

This post explains it better:
[How to generate pdf files _with_ utf-8 multibyte characters using Zend Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173503/how-to-generate-pdf-files-with-utf-8-multibyte-characters-using-zend-framework)

Essentially the built-in fonts (eg. Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA) don't contain enough info, so you need to attach a font ttf file with the pdf, and set your script to use that font.

```
$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath('/Library/Fonts/Times.ttf');
$pdfPage->setFont($font, 36);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will answer your question:

[How to generate pdf files _with_ utf-8 multibyte characters using Zend Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173503/how-to-generate-pdf-files-with-utf-8-multibyte-characters-using-zend-framework)

By the looks of it the default fonts do not have all the utf-8 characters...you may have to load external TTF...