# Zend PDF charset - croatian chartchters not suported - tried everything please HELP

Tags: zend-framework, pdf, character-encoding

Here is my code to create PDF document I cant see č ć ž š đ i tried importing .TTF file but can t import and use ttf properly please help
    $pdf = new Zend_Pdf();

```
// Add new page to the document
$page = $pdf->newPage(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
$pdf->pages[] = $page; 

// Draw something on a page
// Set font
$page->setFont(Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_COURIER), 20); 

///tried to import TTF not working
//$goodDogCoolFont = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath('dokumenti/cro.TTF');
//$page->setFont($goodDogCoolFont, 36);

// Draw text
#
$page->setFillColor(Zend_Pdf_Color_Html::color('#990000'));
$page->drawText('Račćšđžčun za apartman AID '.$this->ukupnacjena[1]['AID'] , 10, 800, 'Windows-1250');// UTF-8 Also doesnt work

pdfData = $pdf->render(); 

$filename = $this->ukupnacjena[1]['OD-DO'];

header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$filename.'.pdf"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
echo $pdfData;
```

Comment: Zend_Pdf uses CP1252 (WinLatin1) for drawing text with standard fonts.

Answer (score 9):

I was facing similar issues with German Characters and found solution by replacing such characters[UMLAUTS in my situation] with its equivalent HTML Code like :

```
$str='German chars &uuml; &auml; &ouml;';
$str = html_entity_decode($str, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
$page->drawText($str, 115, 524,"UTF-8");
```

### Will Print

```
German chars ü ä ö
```

May help you.....

Comment: Thanks for your reply, There is no UMLAUTS for Č Ć Š Đ Ž charachters i tried HTML encoding doesn t help Zend PDF uses Latin 1 charset so i think i must import these charachters first, they can t be displayed becouse Zend PDF doesnt know nothing about them :)

Comment: Just try my code with $str = "&#272;"; at the first line, And It should print the "Đ" character on the PDF

Answer (score 0):

I can see similar problems on this post. It i s actually a import problem.
[Unicode characters not showing in Zend_Pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032135/unicode-characters-not-showing-in-zend-pdf)