# How to insert a copyright symbol on Zend_pdf_table component?

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf, zend-pdf

Does anyone know how to insert a copyright symbol on Zend_pdf_table component?

Also another symbol?

Comment: tried © &#169; &copy; result is draw text as error, &#169; &copy;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/240749/779982

Answer (score 1):

The key is knowing the UTF-8 code points for the special characters.

Here's an example:

```
$pdf = new Zend_Pdf();

$pdf->pages[0] = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
$pdf->pages[0]->setFont(Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA), 36);

$pdf->pages[0]->drawText("\xc2\xa9", 200, 400);

$pdf->save( 'test.pdf' );
```

In this example, "\xc2\xa9" is the UTF-8 code point for the copyright symbol. The TM symbol is "\xe2\x84\xa2" and the emdash is "\xe2\x80\x94".

Comment: I solve it by http://stackoverflow.com/a/240749/779982, but also thanks for your ans