# How to have French special character in a PDF?

Tags: pdf, character-encoding, internationalization, zend-pdf

I met some problems when trying to make a PDF in French, for my project. It doesn't show special character like `é , ò, ê....` (their code are for instance `&ecirc;` or `&oacute;`)
 So, thanks to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173503/how-to-generate-pdf-files-with-utf-8-multibyte-characters-using-zend-framework) I tried to include my own font but it gives this kind of messages:

```
PDF error: This font cannot be embedded in the PDF document. If you would like to
use it anyway, you must pass Zend_Pdf_Font::EMBED_SUPPRESS_EMBED_EXCEPTION in the
$options parameter of the font constructor
```

Do you have any idea to solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use default font. Just use encoding **UTF-8** every time you draw a text.

```
$pdf = new Zend_Pdf();
$page = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
$page->drawText("Bonjour Hélène!", 705, 550,'UTF-8');
```

Comment: I confirm that it's the right answer. French special character must uses the right encoding, no need to add a font. Just the right encoding + the right code for the character (eg: &ecirc;). Voted up.